# Date error SAP Commerce Backoffice widget in 2211.6 version

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

My team is migrating the SAP Commerce Hybris to the 2211.6 version, but we are facing a issue in date fields in Backoffice.
When selecting a date in the widget, this error is shown:

> Você deve especificar uma data. Formato: d de MMM de y HH:mm:ss

Translating:

> You must specify a date. Format: d of MMM of y HH:mm:ss

This issue is only happening in the Cloud environment. Does not happen in Local environment.

This issue is also only happening in a specific language. When selected other language, we no longer see this error.

We've tried restarting server, cleaning cache, reseting backoffice, launching a new deployment with downtime.

[image: error screenshot]

edit:

We figured out that the date is being parsed using the time.
Ex: when selected the date "7 of jun of 2023 10:33:51", it is trying to parse the minutes as day, and the hours as the month. So, it tries to set the date 33 of October (33/10).
[image: date parser error]
[image: calendar date picker]